# Find occurences and print asterisks instead of numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I Print * instead of number in the program when the program finds number in the array ... i.e. for example an array has 10 elements and the elements are: 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2

Program should then display output as 1 ***** and 2*****.
How can I do this?
For now, this is my code:

```
int numbers[10],c,n;
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter Numbers ";
        cin>>numbers[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i]==-1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        n=numbers[i];
        c=1;
        for(int j =i+1;j<10;j++)
        {
            if(numbers[j]==n)
            {
                c++;
                numbers[j]=-1;
            }
        }
        cout<<n<<" is Stored "<<c<<" Time in the Array"<<endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding your question, but I think you want to print an asterisk (*) c times. You can use `std::string`'s constructor `std::string(count, char)` to construct a string with *count* copies of *char*.

So `std::string(c, '*')` is what you're looking for, it seems:

```
cout << n << " is Stored " << std::string(c, '*') << " Time in the Array" << endl;
```

Note that it's bad practice to `using namespace std`, as it pollutes the namespace. In general, you might want to have a look at the [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html)